# Zoho XML formatting issue

Tags: xml, zoho

I'm sending form data to ZOHO CRM. I'm adding some variables into the XML variable as follows.

```
 $xml = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Leads>
    <row no="1">
    <FL val="First Name">'.$name.'</FL>
    <FL val="Last Name"> </FL>
    <FL val="Email">'.$email.'</FL>
    <FL val="Phone">'.$phone.'</FL>
    <FL val="Zip Code">'.$zip.'</FL>
    <FL val="Description">'.$lessonType.'</FL>
    <FL val="Lead Source">web</FL>
    <FL val="Referrer URL">'.$refURL.'</FL>
    </row>
    </Leads>';
```

But when I do this I get the following error.

> 4600Unable to process your request. Please verify if the name and
>   value is appropriate for the "xmlData" parameter.

When I replace the variables in the $xml variable with static value and removed concatenation, it is successfully submitted.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks 
Sam

Answer (score 1):

> try to add double quotation mark instead of single, sometimes error
>   occur due to using single quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got this fixed, but I thought I'd throw my 2 cents in here incase its still and issue and/or someone else may have similar problems.

I would start by checking that your variables are escaped properly.  In particular make sure $refURL variable in your code is escapes any '/' characters.

If everything looks okay, I'd double check the required fields.  According to the documentation it says Last Name and Company are required fields.

http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/modules-fields.html#Leads

(I know you said you tested a hard-coded XML document, so I imagine you have covered this already, but I just wanted to throw that out there)

James

Answer (score 0):

This has not been updated in a while. Just in case, you should enclose the data in `CDATA`  tags. This escapes the special characters.

ref: https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/insertrecords.html#Usage_of_'CDATA'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using variable in xml then try this format

```
<row no=\"1\">
    <FL val=\"Home Street Address\">". $post["home_add"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"City\">". $post["city"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"State\">". $post["state"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"Zip Code\">". $post["zip_code"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"Mobile\">". $post["mobile_phone"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"Social Security Num\">". $post["ss"] ."</FL>
    <FL val=\"DOB\">". $post["dob"] ."</FL>
</row>
```